# USACO reports error as my class is public and should match the file

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm doing a simple sum the numbers problem with an input as a text file.

USACO says:

```
test.java:13: error: class main is public, should be declared in a file named main.java

public class main{
```

My class main is declared in a file named `main.java`, so idk what to do.

```
package helloworld;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {
        myMethod();
    }
    static int myMethod() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner File = new Scanner(new File("test.in.txt"));
        int a = File.nextInt();
        int b = File.nextInt();
        int c = a + b;
        return c;
    }
}
```

The classes file name is "`main.java`"

IDE image

[image]

Look in picture above.

im not sure where `test.java` is. in my project, there is only `main.java`

Comment: The error message has the file name right there: `test.java`, your file is indeed not named `main.java`.

Comment: The package name doesn't match, it should be `usaco` not `helloworld`

Comment: The picture above also shows 'Build successful'. So what is your question?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto yes i moved it before i took a screeenshot to test it in a different project and package, so that's not the issue.

Comment: @EJP yes my PC runs it fine, its just the USACO server or whatever gives me this error: "test.java:13: error: class main is public, should be declared in a file named main.java
public class main{
       ^
1 error"

Comment: 'Whatever' doesn't make for much of a question. Try harder.

Comment: I expect that "test.java" is the default filename used when your code was uploaded to the server.  Check the upload instructions to see how to specify the source filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The class's file name is "main.java".

No, the file name is 'test.java':

```
test.java:13: error: class main is public, should be declared in a file named main.java
```